# PERL-5 Regular Expression Treating Apostrophes Oddly

Tags: regex, perl

So I'm running through a rather large set of files and renaming them via Bulk Rename Utility.  This thing allows for renaming via regular expressions working with PERL-5 (or at least that's what it says)  I have a bunch of files that are currently in the format [id] - [song name] - [artist] and need to swap the song name and artist.

The regular expression I'm using to grab the info from the files is:

```
(.*) - (.*) - (.*)
```

Then renaming with:

```
\1 - \3 - \2
```

The problem is for some unknown reason it's failing to match or properly reorganize some files that include apostrophes in their names and I can't figure out why.

Example:

CBE4-08-03 - My Lovin’ (You’re Never Gonna Get It) - En Vogue.zip <-*Fails to match*

CBE4-08-15 - Gangsta's Paradise - Coolio.zip <-*Matches and changes properly*

CBE5-22-11 - Little White Duck - Children’s Favorites.zip <-*Matches, changes to "- Children - Little White Duck.zip"*

The really infuriating part about this is that there have been plenty of times where the program's renamed files with the word "Children's" just fine, yet seems to trip up on others.

I know this isn't a completely programming question, and that it might just be the program I'm using that's messing something up, I'm just curious if there actually is a reason for this that I'm just missing, and if there is it's something that would be good to know for future use.  Thanks for any info.

Comment: Could you perhaps include a code snippet of how you're using the regex?

Comment: Not programming related.

Comment: if any regexp question ever was a programming question, so is this one.  It even has proper input and out examples

Comment: So, this .exe claims to be vaguely perl related, but we don't know which generation of the regex engine we may be trying to talk to...  I also see that the "apostrophes" that don't match are different characters from the "apostrophe" that does match....

Comment: Is [this](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) the "Bulk Rename Utility" you're using? Its manual says it uses [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/). Incidentally, in Perl `$1` is preferred to `\1`; I'm not sure how PCRE deals with that.

Comment: Yeah, it's worth nothing that this isn't Perl. PCRE is *related* to Perl, but diverged a great many years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but you have an actual apostrophe character (`U+0027`) in "Gangsta's Paradise", but a RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (`U+2019`) in the other two file names.

I presume you're on Windows, which means, I think, that file names are stored in UTF-16. It appears that either the [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/) or the [PCRE library](http://www.pcre.org/) it uses doesn't work correctly with characters outside the 8-bit range.

I don't know why it should fail (`.*` should match any sequence of characters, however they're represented), but *something* is going wrong.

Comment: Ok, well that's probably the source of the problem then. Couldn't see the difference in the application, can barely see it here. At least I can stop pulling my hair out trying to figure out why it's working for some and not for others.

Comment: I'm not sure but Perl5.6 I think was the advent of Unicode in that language. Even if it was a control sequence, it should have been picked up by `.`, unless it is a possible EOS sequence? Maybe FF (-1).

Comment: My guess would be that it isn't the apostrophe, but rather that the - isn't U+002D but rather U+2010 or U+2013 or some such.

Comment: @ysth: The `-` character in the question is a genuine `U+002D`, not a `U+2013`.

Comment: @ysth: And since the pasted text shows both apostrophe and RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK characters, it seems reasonable to assume that it accurately reflects the actual file names.

Answer (score 1):

test program in perl

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @td = ( q|CBE4-08-03 - My Lovin’ (You’re Never Gonna Get It) - En Vogue.zip|,           q|CBE4-08-15 - Gangsta's Paradise - Coolio.zip|,
           q|CBE5-22-11 - Little White Duck - Children’s Favorites.zip|);

for my $r (@td) {
    $r =~s/(.*) - (.*) - (.*)/\1 - \3 - \2/;
    close($file);
}
```

This did not show the reported behaviour.  My version of the command

```
rename 's/(.*) - (.*) - (.*)/\1 - \3 - \2/' *.zip
```

Also worked fine

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try a few different things.

`^(.*)-(.*)-(.*)$`

`^(.+)-(.+)-(.+)$`

`^([\S\s]*)-([\S\s]*)-([\S\s]*)$`

`^([\S\s]+)-([\S\s]+)-([\S\s]+)$`

In all cases, don't but a free space there.

Comment: I used the spaces because hyphens sometimes show up in the middle of a song name, but it's always surrounded by spaces when it's separating the separate bits of data.  Either way I tried your examples with my first example and it's matching, but the name is being changed to " - - .zip".  So taking away the spaces makes it match but it isn't storing anything. :S